# How do I retrieve the authenticated user (not using the default user table) - Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, authentication

I logged in however it does not retreive the logged user.
I tried `Auth::check()` but returns false and I also tried `echo Auth::user()`, does not show anything as well as `echo Auth::id()`.

I'm not using the default user table but I believe everything is set accordingly. No error, just empty results but I successfully log in and redirect the user using this:

```
   if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        // Authentication passed...
        return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
    }
```

Comment: where are you trying to retrieve the User using `Auth::user()` ?

Comment: In my controller and trying to display it on my view. But just returns false. When I try to display `Auth::user()` shows nothing. It's a little bit complicated for me to follow along with Laravel's tutorial as I'm not using th default user model/table shipped with Laravel.

Comment: so i would imagine that means you don't have the `auth` middleware applied to that 'dashboard' route ... this route is in the 'web' group of middleware? in the `web.php` route file?

Comment: In my controller I have `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;` and the method to get the user and in my view: `{{Controller::getUser()}}` .

Comment: you shouldn't have a need to call controllers from views .. you would get the user via `Auth::user()` in the view .... is there a reason you have customized the `login` instead of using the default out of the box?    still assuming all these routes are in the `web.php` file?

Comment: Yes beucase I need different logins: for user and admin. Yes I have routes in my `web.php`  file. I'm succesfully redirected.

Comment: and how are you doing that? because `Auth::user()` means use the default guard to find the user .. .if you have multiple guards how are you dealing with this?

Comment: That's what I don't understand. I have created a new `guard` for the admin login. Does it have something to do with it?

Comment: you have to use the correct guard for the user you are trying to authenticate ... if you used the 'admin' guard to log them in then only the 'admin' guard would authenticate them, that is the whole point of different guards

Comment: Oh thank you for your clarification and feedback. By the way, how would I do that? Something like `Auth::user()->guard('admin')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are not using the default guard, you need to specify it when using the Auth Facade.
For instance, with your admin guard, it will look like:
`Auth::guard('admin')->user();`

See https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#authenticating-users

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm completely to Laravel. Kinda hard to figure that out.

Comment: Hi, @Marinov I changed the default guard to employee  syntax -->  'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'employee',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ], 
but I can't get the current login user from Auth::guard('employee')->user()